# Gather kubectl logs data to an external service

Tags: kubernetes, istio, kubernetes-on-premises

When I run `kubectl logs MyPodNameHere` I get back the standard-out of that pod.

My company has a central logging service for all our applications and I would like to send the `logs` output to that service.  (Via an `HTTPS` endpoint.)

But I can't seem to find a way to hook into a Kubernetes API to get that working.  **Is there a Kubernetes API or other integration point to do this?**

NOTE: I am also using Istio.  I had hopped that I could use that for this, but I can only see stuff about sending "access logs" in the documnation on Istio.  But it seems to me that it should be possible via Istio as well.

**Anyone know a way to get this `logs` data sent to an HTTPS endpoint?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many products that will ship Kubernetes logs off to a central log server. The kubernetes documentation has [a section on logging](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/logging/) that is a good place to start.

There are a number of existing projects that are designed to ship your local off to a central location:

- [Fluentbit](https://docs.fluentbit.io/manual/installation/kubernetes)
- [Filebeat](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/running-on-kubernetes.html)
- [Vector](https://vector.dev/docs/reference/configuration/sources/kubernetes_logs/)

Etc.

And following some of the suggestions in the Kubernetes documentation I linked to earlier you could probably write your own (or reconfigure your existing host-based solutions to support your Kubernetes environment as well).